# Будет ли модуль оперативной памяти Kingston HyperX FURY Black [HX434C16FB3/16] 16 ГБ поддерживаться на платах socket-1151v2?

Tags: железо

Решил брату на день рождения подарить модуль оперативной памяти Kingston HyperX FURY Black [HX434C16FB3/16] 16 ГБ с частотой 3466, то есть выбрал чтобы и по памяти нормально и по частоте запас был если задумает апгрейд. Вот только у меня сомнения будет ли его плата на socket 1151v2 поддерживать модуль с такой частотой? Подскажите пожалуйста кто в теме.

Comment: Нужна конкретная плата и конкретный биос, без этой информации ответ будет угадайкой.

Comment: Здравствуйте, плата вот такая MSI H310M PRO-VDH PLUS, по BIOS у меня информации нет.

Answer (score 1):

Указанная частота модуля памяти - это максимальная частота, на которой он может работат. Если если эта частота выше, чем максимальная частота, которую поддерживает плата, то память работает на более низкой частоте (той, которую плата еще поддерживает). Т.е. в данном случае на 2666.

*Тут просто напрашивается аналогия с автомобилем: проедет ли автомобиль, максимальная скорость которого 200км/ч, по дороге, где разрешено ехать 100 км/ч.*

Comment: Склонялся с такому же ответу, просто дело в том что за частотой 2666 уже много что выпустили, и socket 1200 уже почти вытеснил 1151v2 из продаж, поэтому решил подстраховаться и спросить у тех кто в теме. Благодарю за ответы!